# Synchronize my local maven repository to Nexus public repository

Tags: java, maven, synchronization, nexus, artifacts

I have a local repository which I have been installing jars to for a while from different projects. We also have a nexus server running, but it does not have all the jars that I have locally.

I can try to synchronize jars up to nexus one by one. But is there a more efficient way to synchronize up to nexus? Ideally I would want to execute a single command which would look through all the artifacts in my local repo, and push anything which is missing in nexus.

If a cmd script is the only way, it would be very useful with specific tips around this as well.

I might give an update on my progress so far

```
echo off
echo MavenSync
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R . %%f in (*) do (
  set jarfile=%%~dpnxf
  set name=%%~dpnf
  set pomFile=!name!.pom
  set clientJar=!name!-client.jar

  if [!jarfile:~-4!]==[.jar] (
    echo !jarfile!
    echo !pomFile!
    set repo=http://server/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

    if [!jarfile:~-10!]==[client.jar] (

      rem Handled elsewhere

    ) else (

      if [!jarfile:~-12!]==[SNAPSHOT.jar] (
        set repo=http://server/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
      )

      if EXIST !clientJar! (
        echo mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=!repo! -DpomFile="!pomFile!" -Dfile="!jarfile!" -Dfiles="!clientJar!" -Dtypes=client-jar -Dclassifiers=bin
      ) else (
        echo mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=nexus -Durl=!repo! -DpomFile="!pomFile!" -Dfile="!jarfile!"
      )

    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Basic issue is that all project should have to deliver into the Nexus server...that solves the whole problem...

Answer (score 0):

The Maven goal `deploy:deploy-file`

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

can deploy single artifacts to Nexus (with attached pom, so you don't need to specify the GAV manually).

You need to write a script that runs over your local repository, gathers all artifacts and uses above goal to deploy them to Nexus.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question?

Comment: @robjwilkins My answer is probably much more helpful than yours. The OP says that the jars already exist. I offer a path how to write a script that repairs the given situation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no means of doing this easily without writing a custom script.  However, if you have a build which build everything and installs it locally via `mvn install` then you can deploy it to your nexus by doing `mvn deploy`.  For this to work you need to add a section to your pom for `distributionManagement`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshot.nexus</id>
        <url>${nexus.snapshot.repo}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>release.nexus</id>
        <url>${nexus.release.repo}</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

This will just deploy the latest version of each project however, and not the back history of the older versions.

Depending on the version of nexus that you are using it may be possible to copy the contents of your file system.  Nexus 2 uses file system based storage, so you could potentially compare your .m2 repo with the remote one and copy over the different projects as required.  Once the necessary changes were copied across, a reindex of the remote repo should pick up the changes you made.  Nexus 3 stores the artefacts in a database however, so if you are using that version this wouldn't be possible.